# Does JvmManager and Task in Hadoop reside on same machine

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

JvmManager in hadoop 0.20 handles the task, it runs them and kill them when neccessary.

My question is, does this JvmManager reside on the same machine as this task,
the reason is, I want to run a system command from this JvmManager using the pid of the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My question is, does this JvmManager reside on the same machine as this task, the reason is, I want to run a system command from this JvmManager using the pid of the task.
```

Yes